# how to make the code been invisible

Tags: php, invisible

I finished my php code and want to put it on the server.But I do not want to make it visible for others,and the code can be executed by the server.That means users cannot see it,but the server can see,understand and execute.So How to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: @Pramod: ahahaaha, what an answer...

Comment: @BhavikShah :) Just Joking

Comment: If can,I want to lock it.I wish.^_^

Answer (score 4):

PHP source isn't served as ASCII to browsers like Javascript or CSS. Rather, it is run on the server and the output is sent back to the browser. So, you don't have to worry about users downloading your PHP source, unless you messed up your Apache installation to not parse PHP files (hint: unless you tried to do this, you probably didn't).

With that said, I like to keep my PHP include files outside of the web root whenever possible. This means that users won't be able to execute these scripts, but the scripts that they will execute can include them.

For example, if your `index.php` file is in `/var/site/www`, I'd put all the PHP files I can in `/var/site/inc`.

Comment: Maybe I didn't say it clearly.I want to make my codes that are on the server been invisible  which means other people can not see,apart from me.My English is poor,Sorry about that.Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want to give edit access to yourself only to the server? I think you can solve that via FTP accounts.

Comment: Thank you for your patience to answer.I decide to use Zend Guard.And it looks very simple and very useful.The only disadvantage is that it is not free.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what leads you to need something like this? I've never run into this problem before.

Comment: Work，work and work.It's also my first practical work.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side scripting language and as such when served to the client will always be invisible.

Now if your asking how to secure your web server that has to do with which web server you are running (likely apache). Those settings are altered via the configuration file.

Comment: Yes,I want to secure my web server . And protect my code that are on the server from being visible by others except me.I know that it will always be invisible on the client,But I also don't want to make it visible on the server.My English is poor,Sorry about that.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

php code can only be seen at server side. If you are operating at the server side, than why there is any risk of it being seen by others?

Comment: Than you for your patience to answer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, I would recommend that you look up and use one of the following:

- If you are on Windows, look up [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)
- If you are on Linux, look up [LAMP](http://www.lamphowto.com/)
- If you are on OSX, look up [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html)

These are all packages containing Apache, MySQL and PHP. (That's what "AMP" stands for, while W/L/M stands for "Windows"/"Linux"/"Mac".

When you've installed one of the above, just put the files in the htdocs-folder inside the server-folder and visit your localhost/ IP to see your code in action without actually being able to view your code.

Comment: Than you for your patience to answer.